# Load and apply a mask in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

I have a scrip tin python in which I load some images and apply masks over them. I have those masks in files (jpg) with white and black parts depending on what I want to use.

I am trying to implement that in C++ to see if I can improve its performance (not the opencv part but the rest of the script). 
I am finding really hard to load and apply masks in c++. I tried to load as an image and just draw them on screen but I get an error about opencv can't load them. Normal images works fine.

```
Mat img_mask   = imread("./images_template/masks/"+maskTrainImageArray[i]),0);
img_object.copyTo(img_mount, img_mask);       //Apply mask
```

img_mount is where I want to keep the image with mask applied and img_object where I have the real image.

What do I need to do in order to load the mask and allow the script to apply it?

Comment: `img_object.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0,0), ~img_mask)`

Comment: Thank you, but this makes the whole image to be black, not only the black parts.

Comment: your code looks fine. Can you include examples of `img_mask` and `img_object`?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/carlosmccosta/Currency-Recognition/tree/master/CurrencyRecognition/imgs/currencyDB_mediumResolution I am using images from this site.

Comment: ok, my fault. I mixed png with jpg for masks. Your solutions works fine. Thank you again!